# java Files.isWritable is distorted when running from root

Tags: java, linux, permissions, root

im trying to run an application that check files permissions, and alerts if file is writable.
Files.isWritable(file_path)

when running this application from root access, it returns true, even though 'ls -l' shows that the files has no 'w' access. this is all well, and understood, since root cna actually override permission.

but it leaves me with the issue of checking if the file is writable or not (general access privileges).
is there a way for java to get the 'general' access rights, while running with root?

Comment: I don't have a Linux computer to test this on, but perhaps [`Files#getPosixFilePermissions(Path,LinkOption...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#getPosixFilePermissions(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.LinkOption...)) is what you're looking for.

Comment: So don’t run it as root. Root can do anything, certainly including writing to read-only files. Do not use.